# Show the price of a product in WooCommerce after a button is clicked by the customer

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

The customer asked for the prices to not be visible for each product on the e-shop until the customer clicks on a button. So far jQuery/javascript, as a solution to this, seem more appropriate, I was wondering if there is something else I am missing (code wise, in PHP for example) that would help out more.

Comment: can you show me example code!!!

Comment: 'add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html','on_button_click');
function on_button_click($price){
if(user_clicks_button() ){
    return $price;
}'

I guess this is sort of what I had in mind adding in the functions.php. Not with the exact wording, but something like that.

Comment: You can do it with jQuery, just hide amount on page load and show when user click on 'add to cart' button, @raghu has given answer, check this example  http://jsfiddle.net/raghuchandrasorab/njt1sfew/1/

Comment: Yes, I did see. Thank you too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I request you to post what you have tried before asking in SO in future!

though Solution is here

```
<div class="product-image">
    <p class="prod-name">Product Name</p>  
    <p class="prod-price" style="display:none" >$1000</p>  
    <input type="button" class="show-price" value="show price"/>
</div>
```

Css

```
.product-image{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
}

.prod-name,.prod-price{
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

JS

```
$('.show-price').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('.prod-price').show();
});
```

Working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/raghuchandrasorab/njt1sfew/1/

Comment: I will keep in mind about posting my experiments along with my question.
Your Solution really helps as a great point to start.
Thank you very much.

Comment: You are most welcome! accept & up vote the answers if you are satisfied! Thanks

Comment: Just accepted. (cant up vote yet, though). I will not forget to return and do so, tho, as soon as I can! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Sure also works just with php but the page would need to refresh so i recommend using Javascript onclick event that show a hidden field when activated.
Not sure if this answers your question since im not quite sure what it was.

Comment: I was told about the refresh of the page, if I used PHP, so I guess jquery/javascript on click is my way to go.
Thank you very much for your time!